# Implementing spring-websockets in play 1.2x

Tags: playframework, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I am overhauling the websocket functionality of a play app, and would like to have an application layer protocol like STOMP at my disposal. I have embarked down the path of bringing spring-websockets into the mix, but am having trouble connecting routing incoming requests to my message handlers.

Section 21.2.1 of [this docuemnt](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) indicated that:

> The above is for use in Spring MVC applications and should be included
>   in the configuration of a DispatcherServlet. However, Spring’s
>   WebSocket support does not depend on Spring MVC. It is relatively
>   simple to integrate a WebSocketHandler into other HTTP serving
>   environments with the help of WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.

I have been looking for some examples of an application that has utilized WebSocketHttpRequestHandler in this way, and have yet to find it.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Thanks,
Jeremy

---

To update on this, after two weeks of trying to get this integration to work out for us we threw in the towel. The heart of our issue seemed to be the inability to map play's request object anything spring could recognize. Because of this we were not able to get a handshake negotiated.

Some things we did not try that MAY yeild something:
1) Deploying play as .war so that there would be a serverlet request that you could get at.
2) Or maybe you could let play negotiate the handshake and once you have a socket connection you may be able to pass that to spring...

But at the end of the day we put way to much effort into trying to make this work and have decided that we are going re-implement our application entirely in spring.